# How to get a case of enum in one line?

Tags: swift, enums

I have a `enum` with some `case`, and a array with instances of this `enum`, for example:

```
enum MyEnum {
    case foo(Int)
    case bar(Int)
    case baz(Int)
}

let myArray = [
    MyEnum.foo(1),
    MyEnum.bar(2),
    MyEnum.baz(3)
]
```

Then, I need to compare if determinate element of this array if `foo`, `baz` or `baz`, for example:

```
myArray.filter { $0 == .foo } // not work, and should need return [MyEnum.foo(1)]
```

I can use `switch`:

```
myArray.filter {
    switch $0 {
    case .foo(_):
        return true
    default:
        return false
    }
} // work, and return [MyEnum.foo(1)]
```

But, I want a solution less verbose, and learning more about `enum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **really** want to do it in one line, you can use reflection:

```
myArray.filter { Mirror(reflecting: $0).children.first!.label! == "foo" }
```

Answer (score 4):

The shortest I can think of is:

```
let result = myArray.filter { if case .foo = $0 { return true } else { return false } }
```

Comment: @vacawama ah yes, you are right. 3 characters shorter

Comment: `let result = myArray.filter { if case .foo = $0 { return true }; return false }`

Comment: Great! Thank you. I did not know `if case` statement. But, why compiler don't allow I use `case .foo = $0`, like `1 == 2`?

Comment: That is unfortunately a limitation of Swift. You can only use `case` with `switch`, `if`, `guard` and `for`. Also note that the there is only one equal sign, because this is an "pattern binding" operation, not a conditional check

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before if case is a good solution since swift 2.0. But if you're going to use this same filter many times, then you will need a more expressive way to do this. For instance, you can make this enum equatable hiding your `switchCase` away from the viewController:

```
extension MyEnum: Equatable{
    static func ==(lhs: MyEnum, rhs: MyEnum) -> Bool{
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case (.foo(_), .foo(_)):
            return true
        case (.bar(_), .bar(_)):
            return true
        case (.baz(_), .baz(_)):
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

and then:

```
myArray.filter {
      $0 == .foo(1)
}
```